# Possible to control movieclip components from another movieclips?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs3

I want to control movieclip "A" components from movieclip "B".

movieclip A :

```
function click1(event:MouseEvent):void
{ 
  // I want to change text of button which is inside movieclip "B" in here.
}

btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , click1);
```

movieclip B :

```
function click2(event:MouseEvent):void
{ 
  //and here I want to change text of button which is inside movieclip "A".
}

btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , click2);
```

how can I do this?

sorry for my English.

Answer (score 3):

Making the assumption that both movieclips (`mca` and `mcb`) have been added to the `stage` -- `stage` is the parent of both -- it is as simple as:

```
function click1(event:MouseEvent):void
{ 
    // I want to change text of button which is inside movieclip "B" in here.
    stage.mca.someButtonObject.label = "some new button text";
}

function click2(event:MouseEvent):void
{ 
    //and here I want to change text of button which is inside movieclip "A".
    stage.mcb.someTextboxObject.text = "some new text";
}
```

Test this code out a bit, and let me know if that doesn't work (and please post your code if it fails).

Comment: If you declare your code in the parent of the 2 MovieClips you would have the scope to be able to just say `mca.someButtonObject.label =...` instead of including the `stage`

Comment: @ToddBFisher Thanks for pointing out the more general case.  In theory, use a common ancestor (parent, etc. . . usually the closest).